# "Yea, I can hear them" I just heard this from my computer speakers

Tags: spyware

Randomly I heard a man's voice from our home Mac, "yea, I can hear them"

There were no internet windows open. We cover our camera with a sticker, call us paranoid but are we really? NO!

Does anyone know how I can find out how, why, where, who is listening in on me?!?!?!?

Comment: Remote access trojan...

Comment: [Micro Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html) program just for that (built by a company behind Little Snitch).

Answer (score 2):

Install [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) for Mac and reboot. You can use the filter to limit external communications to just those that you explicitly authorize. If it's an ongoing thing, just disconnect for a while to see if it persists.

If you're really worried about it and don't want to monitor network connections, you could always block the microphone. On my MacBook, I used a few layers of electrical tape to cover the microphone (didn't fall off until a while after I stopped being paranoid). To find the microphone(s) on your machine, you can open QuickTime Player, click `File > New Audio Recording`, turn the volume up, and tap around the chassis. Use headphones to eliminate reverb loops while testing.

Really doubt an eavesdropper would use a two-way stream.